# Deploy Django with VueJS on DigitalOcean Apps

Tags: django, vue.js, deployment, digital-ocean

I have a project that consists of `Django (DRF)` backend and `VueJS` app frontend.

During development, I have two servers - Django deployment server on port 8000 and VueJS on port 8080.

I would like to make this work also on `DigitalOcean Apps` platform so the only thing I need to deploy it is to `git push` project to master.

Structure:

```
django_project/django_project/settings.py ...
django_project/django_app1
django_project/django_app2
django_project/vue_app
```

If I deploy this, only `Django` project is being server. I need to bound `VueJS` project to `/` URL and `Django` to `/api` url.

I have some ideas but I'm not sure how to make them work. For example, I'll setup `outputDir` to `/var/www` but I can't access the nginx configuration so I don't know how to do that.

Do you have any ideas?